# Finding Bounds, Proof by Induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I am trying to prove the upper bound is at most 12 and the lower bound is at least 1/2 for a sequence where $a_1$ = $1$ and $a_{n+1} = 5 + 2/a_n$, using induction. I tried it so my base case is $a_1 = 1$, and I established that $a_k > 1/2$. From here, $1/a_k < 2$ and $2/a_k < 4$. However, this is going nowhere and I'm wondering if this is even the correct solution.

Comment: If $2/a_k<4$ then $a_{k+1}=5+2/a_k<9<12$

Comment: Are you sure about you lower bound? Since $a_n>0$, $a_{n+1}>5$. Every number in the sequence is greater than $5$, except $a_1$.

Answer (score 3):

We shall prove that $5<a_n<6$ for all $n\in \{3,4,5,\cdots\}$. We have that

$$a_2=5+\frac{2}{a_1}=5+2=7$$

$$a_3=5+\frac{2}{7}=5.28571$$

So the proposition holds for $n=3$. Now suppose it hold for some $n\geq 3$ and consider $a_{n+1}$: Obviously

$$a_{n+1}=5+\frac{2}{a_n}>5$$

However, we also know that

$$a_{n+1}=5+\frac{2}{a_n}<5+\frac{2}{5}=5.4<6$$

Thus, $5<a_n<6$ for all $n\in\{3,4,5,\cdots\}$. Additionally, $\frac{1}{2}<a_1,a_2<12$ which satisfy your bounds.

Comment: I know it makes sense in this for n >=3, but does that count as a full proof if you have that condition rather than having n start at 1?

Comment: Yes, you can always check a finite number of cases and ensure they satisfy the bounds and then do induction for the rest. If you really want to convince yourself, define $a_1=5+2/7$ and show that it works for all natural numbers (same proof as above, just shifted by $2$)

Answer (score 1):

Hint: See that the sequence oscillates back-and-forth & converges to a particular value. This value is nothing but the continued fraction; (which could be solved by $5+2/x=x$)
$$5+\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{5+\frac{2}{...}}}=\frac{5+\sqrt{33}}{2}\simeq 5.3722813232$$

By this, you can see that the sequence hits a maximum & minimum possible values, in the process of 'oscillation', at $n=1$ & $n=2$. Or;
$$a_1>a_n>a_2 \tag{for $n∈ℕ,n>2$}$$
$$7>a_n>\frac{37}{7}$$